# Where can I find Apple's list of IPSWs for Apple Silicon macs?

Tags: macos, ipsw

I've seen multiple [sites](https://mrmacintosh.com/apple-silicon-m1-full-macos-restore-ipsw-firmware-files-database/) that show links of links to Big Sur or Monterey software restore files, but none of them explicitly stating their source. I know that iOS, Watch, TV, iPad OS restore files are seen [here](https://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml). But where are the macOS IPSWs stored? A quick google search for one IPSW (UniversalMac_11.6_20G165_Restore.ipsw) in quotation marks showed nothing. Sucatalogs wouldn't have them, right? I've used SUS inspector to check out large files and they aren't IPSWs.

The difference between an IPSW and something like a [regular macOS installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)? - IPSWs have only been available for Big Sur and above, and are the only available file types that can be used with the virtualization framework on a M1 mac.

Comment: Non-Apple IPSW files from any source that does not end in "apple.com" I, personally, would not trust, install or use. They are, for all intents and purposes, pirated software. Also an IPSW is a function of iOS devices **only.** MacOS is only available as a downloadable installer from apple.com.

Comment: But how would you explain one of the download links from the site I attached? That goes to `updates.cdn-apple.com` which [appears](https://who.is/whois/cdn-apple.com) to be owned by apple.

Answer (score 0):

### https://mesu.apple.com/assets/macos/com_apple_macOSIPSW/com_apple_macOSIPSW.xml

I found it when I was looking for a download of `SeedCatalogs.plist` from the `Seeding.framework` to automate getting the latest `suscatalog` files, and originally found the ipsw links here: https://gist.github.com/b0gdanw/43d5c9e5f44a20e9a70c247ff8259f46

Comment: It doesn't have some of them.  For example, https://ipsw.me/download/MacBookAir10,1/20D91
links to http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2021WinterFCS/fullrestores/071-14756/5676903C-6D55-4412-B9DF-969F15F5491A/UniversalMac_11.2.3_20D91_Restore.ipsw which is not in com_apple_macOSIPSW.xml.  That's updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2021WinterFCS/fullrestores/071-14756/5676903C-6D55-4412-B9DF-969F15F5491A/UniversalMac_11.2.3_20D91_Restore.ipsw  [EDIT: OH! And we can trust cdn-apple.com as it's in the xml file off apple.com !]

Comment: Actually, *currently* it only contains *one* IPSW link - https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2022SummerFCS/fullrestores/012-51674/A7019DDB-3355-470F-A355-4162A187AB6C/UniversalMac_12.5.1_21G83_Restore.ipsw

Comment: This is a link-only answer